# hide action button if roles have relationship with users

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am working on Role Based authentication in Laravel and every thing works fine but I have problem in Role section.
I want to hide action buttons like Edit and Delete from my Roles List Page those roles which have been assigned to users can't be delete but other roles which haven't assigned to user yet can be deleted.

**Role Migration**

```
<?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('role_typ');
                $table->string('role_name');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
        }
    }
```

**User migration**

```
class AddColumnsToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });
    }
```

**user model**

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
}
```

**Role Controller**

```
 // Role Management
    public function Rolelist()
    {
        $roles = Role::paginate(10);
        
        
        return view('admin.roles', compact('roles'));
    }
```

**Role list blade page**

```
<div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title">All Role List</h3>
                                <div class="card-tools">
                                    <a href="{{ route('roleform') }}" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm">Add Role <i
                                            class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-header -->
                            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
                                <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Role Name</th>
                                            <th>Role Type</th>
                                            <th>Created</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   
                                        <tbody> 
                                            @foreach ($roles as $role)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{ $role->id }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $role->role_name }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $role->role_typ }}</td>
                                                <td> {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($role->created_at))->diffForHumans() }}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                    
                                    
                                </table>
                                
                            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... to hide that you need to create relationship in your model did you added that ?

Comment: The easiest way of doing this is to create a Blade directive and use it to display role-based content. Please check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#custom-if-statements

Comment: That I Know but how to make that logic to only display action buttons for roles which don't have any relation with user model

Comment: @if($role->id = 1)
<button>View</button>
@else
<button>Edit</button>

Comment: Why don't you try this one [Spatie role permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Role model you should have users method which contains HasMany relationship to User model. After that when you get the roles you should use Role::withCount('users');

Then in the blade file you can use $role->users_count to check how many users you have attached to this role.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models